# Retrieving values from nested JSON after de-serialization

Tags: java, web-services, rest, collections, json-deserialization

I am trying to test my REST service by a JSON string from Chrome's Advanced REST Client. I have a nested JSON here. I am taking this as string and mapping it to my POJO class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(addressString, AddressPOJO.class);
```

Here, *addressString* holds the JSON String given below

```
{
 "location":"[{\"Asia\":[{\"India\":[{\"city\":\"Bengaluru\"}]}], [{\"India\":[{\"city\":\"Mumbai\"}]}]}]
}
```

My AddressPOJO has variable:

```
Map<String,?> location = new HashMap();
```

I am retrieving the values from the POJO by

```
Map<String, ?> locations = addressPOJO.getLocation();
Iterator iterator1 = locations.entrySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry pair1 = (Map.Entry)iterator1.next();
    Map<String,?> cities = (Map<String,?>) pair1.getValue();
    Iterator iterator2 = dataSets.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry pair2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
        Map<String,?> city = (Map<String, ?>) pair2.getValue();
    }
}
```

Here, I am only able to retrieve the second entry which is

```
[{\"India\":[{\"city\":\"Mumbai\"}]}]
```

I need to retrieve all the entries. I also tried to use MultiMap like this

```
MultiMap cities = (MultiMap) pair1.getValue();
```

But this is not accepted by compiler. Please note all the entries are dynamic in nature and the (key, value) pairs change as per user's input. Any suggestions how I can retrieve all the entries in this example.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, maybe there are 2 things that you need to look into:

1. Why the data type of `location` is `Map<String, ?>`? Because from your JSON string, the type of `location` is an `Array` or a `List`, right? If you want to make it a `Map`, please use some strings like: `{"location" : "\"key\":\"value\""}`. If you want to make it a `List`, remove the **""** around the value.
2. Another thing is that, it seems that you want a hierarchy to describe the some geography structure. Let's say, in `Asia` we have `India` and `China`, and in `India` we have `Bengaluru` and in `China` we have the city `Chengdu`. So the value of `Asia` should also be a `List` which contains two items `India` and `China`. So you should remove the **]** and **[** here, and I think this is also the reason why you are only able to retrieve the second entry.

   [image]

Following is my testing code, I modified your JSON string and the data type of `location`.

**Location.java**

```
public class Location {
    private List location;

    public List getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(final List location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

**TestJSON.java**

```
public class testJson {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        final String locationString = "{\"location\":[{\"Asia\":[{\"India\":[{\"city\":\"Bengaluru\"}]}, {\"India\":[{\"city\":\"Mumbai\"}]}]}]}";
        final Location location = mapper.readValue(locationString, Location.class);

        System.out.println("finish");
    }
}
```

Then all entries and levels are ok. Maybe you can have a try.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I must have mentioned that I am removing all '[' chars from JSON before mapping it to the POJO. My frontend guy may be using arrays to generate JSON and hence '['. Also, the example I gave here is not the exact thing I am dealing with. I just gave some sample wording. So, as mentioned I get the key "India" more than once. Its not gonna be unique. I am now making it unique by trailing it with '_' and some random number. Let me know if I can deal with it without using random number. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Abhiram, anyway I think it's better for you to not use "Map" because in your example the location string is not a map but a "List". If you want to use map, try "LinkedHashMap" because it's always how ObjectMapper represent an Object.